# How to find city name in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, google-maps, mapkit

How to find city name in iPhone SDKs from google api?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOURADDRESS&sensor=true

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you create google api key at [this link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and then insert it into the code below.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=true&key=<your api key here>",your_textField_search_str]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);  
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[json objectWithString:returnString error:nil]];
```

Comment: Great answer but you shouldn't include any account-specific API keys because they could be abused. I've removed them from the post